# Abstract method error when combining akka 2.3.7, reactive mongo and spray

Tags: akka, spray, reactivemongo

Application dependencies are:

```
com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.3.7
org.reactivemongo#reactivemongo_2.10:0.10.5.0.akka23
org.reactivemongo#play2-reactivemongo_2.10:0.10.5.0.akka23
```

and a couple of spray libs all of version 1.3.1
When starting the appliction I get

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:580)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:279)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

PS: I do not use any akka 2.2 compatible libs and I did read similar topics here(the only solution there was to update play from 2.2 to 2.3)

Comment: Do you use sbt? You can look at the output of the `show externalDependencyClasspath` in sbt to see which libraries are actually used for compiling / running from which you may be able to infer where the problem lies.

Comment: Your title says "spray" but your application dependencies include play2-recativemongo. Do you use spray at all ?

Answer (score 0):

I had that error once and it was due to having libraries that depended on different version of Scala. Some required Scala 2.10 and others (I think it were the Akka ones) required Scala 2.11. You should check that out